# Instantiating base class using derived class?

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

Here is my code, I cannot reason out why the output is coming to be like that. If anyone can explain please.

```
import java.io.*;
class b {
void m(b a){
System.out.println(" b");
}  
}
class bcd extends b {
    void m(bcd a){
System.out.println("bcd");
 }  
}
class cde extends bcd {
void m(cde a){
System.out.println("cde");
}  
}
public class ABC{
public static void main(String[] args){
b ob1= new cde();
cde ob2=new cde();
ob1.m(ob2);
}
}
```

Comment: and why does it confuse you?

Comment: It is printing b as output, why not cde ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example will call method in class b. I think you want to show overriding or overloading example, but this is not overriding and not overloading.

For overriding use late binding. In this case, knowing the method signature, the virtual machine analyzes **instantiating(real) type of object** on which this method is called to determine exactly which class to take the definition of the method being called.
For overloading use earlier binding. In this case, compiler checking a **formal type of object**

Good example explain overriding or overloading this:

```
public class Test{

    public static class Parent{

        public void test(){
            System.out.println("parent class");
        }
    }

    public static class Child extends Parent{

        public void test(){
            System.out.println("child class");
        }
    }

    public static class Tester{

        public void test(Parent obj){
            System.out.println("Parent method");
            obj.test();
        }

        public void test(Child obj){
            System.out.println("Child method");
            obj.test();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Parent obj = new Child();
        Tester t = new Tester();
        t.test(obj);
    }
}
```

Result execution:

> Parent method
>
> child class

**EDIT:**
1)Compiler don't look on type the parameter. It determine, what method calling, based on real type object on which it was called: for your example this is b class, for my example this is Tester class.2) if we have two methods in a class with the same name, but different type parameter in the method (overloading), then java virtual machine look on the type parameter(how in my example: two methods with the same name, but transmitted the object of class Parent and calling method with Parent parameter)

In your example if was like this:

```
class B {
   void m(B a){
          System.out.println(" b");
   }  

   void m(Cde a){
         System.out.println("cde");
   }  
}

public class ABC{
       public static void main(String[] args){
          B ob1= new Cde();
          Cde ob2=new Cde();
          ob1.m(ob2);
       }
}
```

It's example overloading and  will call  `void m(cde a)`

**EDIT2:**
Yes, your ob1 object is instance cde, but java virtual machine check instantiating(real) type of object only in case overriding(when signature of methods in two classes are identical). So, you need to remember two things overriding and overloading, in other cases compiler look on formal type reference, in your example this is b.

But there is interesting thing with overriding.

From http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.5

> Return types may vary among methods that override each other if the
>   return types are reference types. The notion of
>   return-type-substitutability supports covariant returns, that is, the
>   specialization of the return type to a subtype.
>
> ```
> A method declaration d1 with return type R1 is return-type-substitutable for another method d2 with return type R2,
> ```
>
> if and only if the following conditions hold:
>
> ```
>     If R1 is void then R2 is void.
>
>     If R1 is a primitive type, then R2 is identical to R1.
>
>     If R1 is a reference type then:
>
>         R1 is either a subtype of R2 or R1 can be converted to a subtype of R2 by unchecked conversion (§5.1.9), or
>
>         R1 = |R2|
> ```

if you have this code with different return type, but identical parameter, it will be example overriding too:

```
class Bcd extends B {
    @Override
    Bcd m(Cde a) {
        System.out.println("bcd");
        return a;
    }
}

class Cde extends Bcd {
    @Override
    Cde m(Cde a) {
        System.out.println("cde");
        return a;
    }
}

class B {
    B m(Cde a) {
        System.out.println("b");
        return a;
    }
}

class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final B ob1 = new Cde();
        final Cde ob2 = new Cde();
        ob1.m(ob2);
    }
}
```

Result:

> cde

Because this is overriding too.

Comment: In my code, why is b getting printed instead of cde. When I am passing object of cde class, like you passed object of parent and it printed parent method, why is it not getting called ?

Comment: but in my example if i m calling ob1.m, cde should be called because right now my reference is at cde, and then i am sending cde object as parameter and so i m expecting cde as output.

Comment: Add some clarifications in the answer.

Comment: in your edit 2, why same is not happening, when i am sending it should go to b, and then when it finds that object is found, it should get printed like my original code is doing. ? Also in my question, is it a case of overriding or overloading ?

Comment: In your example it is not overriding and not overloading cases. Not overriding, because you have DIFFERENT TYPE PARAMETER(in my example I want to show that may be overriding with DIFFERENT RETURN TYPE, but need conditions written above in the answer and IDENTICAL TYPE PARAMETRS).  Not overloading, because methods located in DIFFERENT CLASSES.

Comment: my example is not overriding, alright. but if my program is not overloading, why it is sending cde's object to b's funciton m not anyother ?

Comment: Compiler in your example checks that type your parameter is type b or class extends b, will be compile error if type parameter don't satisfies this condition. BUT IT IS NOT OVERLOADING, because methods located in DIFFERENT CLASSES: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html

Comment: if it is not overloading then why print b in first place and why not cde or bcd. ? this is my doubt. i know now that it is not overloading and neither overriding.

Comment: Compiler look on FORMAL type reference object(not on INSTANCE type) on which calling method. In your example ob1.m(ob2) ob1 formal type is b.

Comment: So, you need to remember two things overriding and overloading, **in other cases** compiler look on formal type reference, in your example this is b.

Comment: I wont bother you now. Thanks a lot for the help :) you were a great help :) perfectly clear on my concepts now.

Answer (score 0):

When you are calling `ob1.m(ob2);` then method of class b is getting invoked. 
The methods defined in class

```
class bcd extends b {
    void m(bcd a) {
        System.out.println("bcd");
    }
}

class cde extends bcd {
    void m(cde a) {
        System.out.println("cde");
    }
}
```

are overloaded methods not overriden methods.